# Get type of variable from parameter using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I get the type of the variable from a parameter using PowerShell?

Something to the effect of **if TypeOf(xyz) is String** or **if TypeOf(xyz) is integer**.

For my purpose I want to check if it is a string or a securestring. I would like to use a single function with a parameter. Not two separate functions, one for a securestring and one for a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use [the `-is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators):

```
if ($xyz -is [String]){}
if ($xyz -is [SecureString]){}

if ($xyz -isnot [int]){}
```

However, digging deeper:

> I would like to use a single function with a parameter. Not two separate functions, one for a securestring and one for a string.

You can use a single function, with [parameter sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) to distinguish between which version you're using:

```
function Do-Thing {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName = 'Secure',
        Mandatory = $true
    )]
    [SecureString]
    $SecureString ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName = 'Plain',
        Mandatory = $true
    )]
    [String]
    $String
)

    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        'Plain' {
            # do plain string stuff
        }

        'Secure' {
            # do secure stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Go ahead and run that sample definition, and then look at the help:

```
Get-Help Do-Thing
```

You'll see the generated parameter sets, which show the two ways you can call it. Each way has a single, mutually-exclusive parameter.

> ```
> NAME
>     Do-Thing
>
> SYNTAX
>     Do-Thing -SecureString <securestring>  [<CommonParameters>]
>
>     Do-Thing -String <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Comment: Hi @briantist.

If I use:

`if ($xyz -is [String]){}`
`if ($xyz -is [bool]){}`
`if ($xyz -is [int]){}`

It works. If I use:

`if ($xyz -is [SecureString]){}`

It will not work. It gets pickedup as a PSOBject or PSCustomObject.
How do I get around that?

Comment: @CostaZachariou well I don't know because I can't see the part of your code that assigns `$xyz`. What is the output of `$xyz.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: Thank you for your help earlier. I think it was because it was returning a null and was changing to the default object of PSCustomObject. That seems to be working now. Creating another question for returning SecureString.